# Expand template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Is there a way to convert each type of std::tuple into specific subtypes?
I have following code

```
struct Foo1
{
    struct A{};
    struct B{};
};

struct Foo2
{
    struct A{};
    struct B{};
};

using myTypes = std::tuple<Foo1, Foo2>;
```

Is there a way to convert myTypes into following type?

```
std::tuple<Foo1::A, Foo1::B, Foo2::A, Foo2::B>;
```

Order of types doesn't matter, but would be nice to have it like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A/B name are fixed, you might do

```
template <typename... Ts>
using AB_Types = std::tuple<typename Ts::A..., typename Ts::B...>;
```

So `AB_Types<Foo1, Foo2>` is `std::tuple<Foo1::A, Foo2::A, Foo1::B, Foo2::B>`.

Having expected order would also be possible:

```
template <typename... Ts>
using AB_Types_ordered =
    decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<typename Ts::A, typename Ts::B>{}...));
```

and if source is a tuple, just add extra layer

```
template <typename>
struct AB_impl;

template <typename... Ts>
struct AB_impl<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = AB_Types<Ts...>; // AB_Types_ordered<Ts...>
};

template <typename T>
using AB_Types_from_tuple = typename AB_impl<T>::type;
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution based on the [`Boost.Mp11`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) library:

```
template<class T>
using add_AB = std::tuple<typename T::A, typename T::B>;

template <typename Tuple>
using AB_Types_from_tuple = 
    boost::mp11::mp_flatten<boost::mp11::mp_transform<add_AB, Tuple>>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    AB_Types_from_tuple<myTypes>,
    std::tuple<Foo1::A, Foo1::B, Foo2::A, Foo2::B>
>);
```